# can avg and count work together in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in my database and they look like this

```
create table restaurants(
restID number(8) NOT NULL,(PK)
name varchar(50),
photo varchar(50))
```

and

```
create table review_Restaurants(
commentID number(8) NOT NULL,
reviewDate timestamp,
commentValue varchar(100),
rating number(1),
userName varchar (25) not null,
restID number(8) not null,);
```

and what i want to do is get the best restaurant(higher ratings and reviews) images out from database and show it on screen.

The way i approached this problem is i'll calculate the avg rating for every rest which ever greater than 3 will be considered and also those who have comments more than 5.

```
select ((avg)rating > 3) as "rating",(count(reviews) > 5) as "review"
from review_restaurant
group by restID;
```

but its not working. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: condition should be handled in HAVING clause

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT restID
     , Avg(rating) As "rating"
     , Count(reviews) As "review"
FROM   review_restaurant
GROUP
    BY restID
HAVING Avg(rating) > 3
AND    Count(reviews) > 5
```

If you were to drop the `HAVING` clause off the above statement it would return all restaraunt reviews and their average rating and number of reviews.

The `HAVING` clause is very similar to a `WHERE` clause but the subtle difference is that the `HAVING` clause applies **after** the aggregation has occurred.

Another alternative approach is to use a subquery

```
SELECT restID
     , rating
     , review
FROM   (
        SELECT restID
             , Avg(rating) As "rating"
             , Count(reviews) As "review"
        FROM   review_restaurant
        GROUP
            BY restID
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  rating > 3
AND    reviews > 5
```

The same logic as using the `HAVING` clause applies here too... We calculate all the average ratings and number of reviews and **then** we apply our criteria.

---

If you want to retrieve the corresponding information from the `restaurants` table then once we need to make our query above a subquery and join it back to the `restaurants` table.

```
SELECT restaurants.restID
     , restaurants.name
     , restaurants.photo
     , top_restaurants.rating As average_rating
     , top_restaurants.review As number_of_reviews
FROM   restaurants
 INNER
  JOIN (
        SELECT restID
             , Avg(rating) As "rating"
             , Count(reviews) As "review"
        FROM   review_restaurant
        GROUP
            BY restID
        HAVING Avg(rating) > 3
        AND    Count(reviews) > 5
       ) As top_restaurants
    ON top_restaurants.restID = restaurants.restID
```

Comment: Isn't this same as mine? I'll give this a try though! Can you also tell me how would i get images out because this query is only giving me the restid

Comment: Well it seems to have different letters and words in a different order ... the HAVING clause for example.